# Passing checked from checkbox to controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Thanks for taking your time to look at my problem.
I have a situation were I want to fetch the checkbox "checked" status and return the corresponding value/id to the controller.

The idea is to add the value of the input field to the points as seen in this picture:

[image]

As you may have found out I want to add 200 points to Prof. Maverick and Sidney (dummy data)

This is supposed to happen when i click the add points button.

I managed to pass the input value to the controller:

A small part of home.blade.php

```
<form action="/addpoints" method="post">
        @csrf
        <div class="field has-addons">
          <div class="control has-icons-left">

            <input class="input" type="tel" placeholder="" id="pointsInput" name="pointsInput">
            <span class="icon is-small is-left">
            <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
          </span>
          </div>
          <div class="control">
            <button class="button is-info" id="addPoints">Add Points</button>

            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

(If the class names looks unfamiliar it's because I'm using Bulma CSS.)

This is what I've tried:

HomeController.php

```
public function addPoints(Request $request)
    {
        $member = new Member; <-- Member model contains a points fillable

        $checked = $request->addPoints;
        $points = $request->pointsInput; <-- this returns the correct data

        return redirect('/home');
    }
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::post('/home', 'HomeController@store');
Route::post('/addpoints', 'HomeController@addPoints')->name('addpoints');
Route::get('/home/{id}', 'HomeController@edit');
Route::patch('/home/{id}', 'HomeController@update');
Route::delete('/home/{id}', 'HomeController@destroy');
Route::get('/home/search', 'HomeController@search')->name('home.search');
```

First part of the table containing the checkbox:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{ $member->id }}" name="addPoints"></td>
  <td>{{ $member->name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $member->email }}</td>
  <td>{{ $member->size }}</td>
  <td>{{ $member->points }}</td>
```

Thank you in advance for having a look at this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should be tracking the value of those checkboxes in a hidden field of your form above. You can simply get all the checked checkboxes and concatinate their unique identifier with jQuery, or whatever you're using.

```
$('#my-form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var checked = [];

    $('.my-checkbox').each(function() {
        let checkboxId = $(this).data('id');

        checked.push(checkboxId);
    });

    $('#my-hidden-field').val(checked);

    $(this).submit();
});
```

After doing so, you can simply get the hidden fields value and use it in PHP side.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your checkboxes with this *form* and they have to be **above** the `button[type=submit]`. But in your situation, it's impossible to do that without crutch (You can put hidden button after the table and emit click on it when you click on `#addPoints`).

But, I think, the best approach is to send form data by Ajax request.